# Can I say that a woman is shocked about something that's happening and standing with 'her eyes ripped wide open'?

Tags: phrasing

I'm writing a story and a woman is negatively surprised about something/ standing in the room in shock. Can I use the phrase 'she stood (in place X), her eyes ripped wide open.' ? I'm not sure if I can use 'ripped' in this case?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better suited for writes.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't the most appropriate, it implies her eyes are forced open very fast by physical force.

'she stood (in place X), her eyes wide in shock.'

Comment: That's what I thought, but I don't really want to add the reason why her eyes are wide open in that sentence because it will be explained in the following one. Could I just say 'she stood (in place X), her eyes wide open'? Or omit the comma and use 'with her eyes wide open?'

Comment: I think this is verging on story writing. If you could give more detail (2 sentences before and after) that might enable us to work out what should fit best. The way it stands does not 'feel' right.

Comment: It also sounds horrifying.